# enable button based on combo box visibility using trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, datatrigger

I am trying to enable a button based on combo box visibility and its selected valued using multidata trigger but doesn't seem to be working.

any help appreciated please.

```
<Multidatatrigger.conditions>
<Condition
    Binding="{Binding ElementName=ComboName, Path=Visibility}"
    Value="Visible"/>
<Condition
    Binding="{Binding ElementName=ComboName, Path=SelectedValue}"
    Value="{x:Null}"/>
</Multidatatrigger.conditions>
<Setter
    Property = "IsEnabled",
    Value = "false"/>
```

the first condition doesnt seem to be working. Even if the combo box is collapsed the button is disabled.

I want the button to be enabled when combo box is visible and a value is selected.

Comment: I think you should post more code, it's hard to tell what's the problem here, such as where you place the `MultiDataTrigger`?, why do you have to use an ElementName here for the Binding, looks like you have more than 1 ComboBox involved....

Comment: I am placing this trigger in button that I want to enable. I am using element name because I want to trigger this based on combo box selected value and its visibility. And its only one combo box that is involved.

Comment: Just made a demo, seems to work fine, intially the Button is disabled (because the SelectedValue is null), after selecting a value, the Button is enabled. Clicking the Button sets the ComboBox's `Visibility` to `Collapsed` or `Hidden` and it's still enabled (not disabled as you said).

Comment: Also I suppose that you mistyped some keywords (posted here, but not in your actual code) which should be case-sensitive, such as `Multidatatrigger` should be `MultiDataTrigger`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `MultiDataTrigger` is evaluated in `AND` mode so in order to be evaluated as true all of the conditions has to be met.

when combo is collapsed the first condition fails hence the whole trigger evaluates to false. hence leaving button enabled.

to over come this issue add another trigger to disable button if combo is collapsed

So here is a complete example to achieve the same

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter" />
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="sampleData"
                            MethodName="GetValues"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="Visibility" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <CheckBox Content="Combo visibility"
              IsChecked="True"
              x:Name="check" />
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboName"
              Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=check,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource sampleData}}" />
    <Button Content="A button">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ComboName, Path=Visibility}"
                                 Value="Collapsed">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                                Value="false" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=ComboName, Path=Visibility}"
                                       Value="Visible" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=ComboName, Path=SelectedValue}"
                                       Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                                Value="false" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

I have wrapped all the necessary controls in a stack paneland then used the triggers in button style to control the same

so as mentioned in the question if all of the condition evaluate to true the the button become disabled.

also if the combo is collapsed the button will remain disabled.

you may adjust the conditions as per your needs

result

[image: result]

Comment: The OP does not need a demo, he wants to know why it does not work. You should at least explan ***what's wrong*** with his code, I've also just made a demo and it seems to work fine, which means there is nothing wrong with the OP's code ***unless*** his code has something else which has not been posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine, at least it does once it has been edited to be valid. It does exactly what you want it to do. Perhaps you have some other code that was interfering with it, but if you test this on its own, you'll see that it *does* work:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox Name="Combo" ItemsSource="{Binding Items" />
    <Button Content="Click me">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Visibility, 
                                ElementName=Combo}" Value="Visible" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding SelectedValue, 
                                ElementName=Combo}" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```